# Crack the cypher: what are the kidnappers asking for?

Tags: cipher

```
S h b i b b t k n e w o p c a a c t l r a s e r u w l t e t a 
o h r s u l w g t e m n u p f a c n e v e a a t o a a c n 
a l e d y l o s n c t e o h p e s e a l e t s l o n y e L e h 
n y h p r e a e t p d n e k w o s t v h y d s t d e b v
```

Your friend is missing, the kidnappers are asking for 12 months supply of something. What is it?

The clue is found in the text above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Decrypting the message:

> Using a railfence cipher with four rails we get:
>
> ```
> S     h     b     i     b     b     t     k     n     e     w     o     p     c     a     a     c     t     l     r
>  a   s e   r u   w l   t e   t a   o h   r s   u l   w g   t e   m n   u p   f a   c n   e v   e a   a t   o a   a c
>   n a   l e   d y   l o   s n   c t   e o   h p   e s   e a   l e   t s   l o   n y   e L   e h   n y   h p   r e   a e
>    t     p     d     n     e     k     w     o     s     t     v     h     y     d     s     t     d     e     b     v
> ```

> And reading along the rails, adding some spacing and punctuation gives us:
> **Santas helper buddy will not be sent back to the workshop unless we get a twelve month supply of candy canes. Leave the candy at the polar bear cave.**
>
>  So we'd better hurry up and get those candy canes over to the cave and hope the polar bears don't eat them all.

Comment: I guess it's not quite as bad as the usual "victim writes a note which reveals the murderer, but in a fit of supreme brilliance, decides to encrypt it", but why would you ever want to encrypt your ransom note? You want your demands to be understood, right?